# TryParseExact doesn't work on string with date and time while format include only date format

Tags: c#, datetime

Any idea why when i have time **"00:00:00"** in my string this does't work ?

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/06/2015 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate)
```

While when i'm doing this it works Ok:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/06/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate)
```

Any help will be much appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: `ParseExact` is not a hint?

Comment: sounds like it...(-;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format, culture-specific
>   format information, and style. **The format of the string representation
>   must match the specified format exactly**.

For your second example they match, but in first example, they don't.

Use `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format instead.

```
string s = "01/06/2015 00:00:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Successfully parsing
}
```

More information at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Soner, it does make sense, I'll just keep the time in the format, and i'll create date render format in my client.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I tried the answer and it didn't work.

It turns out that there was a space character at the beginning of the date string I was trying to ParseExact. (e.g. " 20/08/2019")

So try a close examination of your date string and make sure there's no hidden characters or space characters you didn't spot